# Не отображается Rectangle в окне

Tags: qt, qml

Новичок в QML. Есть код такого содержания:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "green"
    }
}
```

Само окно отображается корректно, в соответствии с указанным размером, но Rectanlgle на форме не отображается, не понимаю, почему так. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня только одно отличие - QtQuick.Controls 2.2 и все работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовала, как указано в комментарии выше - почему то приложение перестало запускаться. Удалила из папки документов папку "build" данного проекта - все заработало как нужно.